# Writing my own Linux distro

Tags: python, c, linux

I had the idea recently to write my own Linux distribution. The idea came from wanting to expand my programming knowledge, I already know a bit of Python and I am starting to learn C for this project.
I was just wondering where to start? I don't actually know how I would begin to write the distro and I would appreciate any help deciding what to do first.

Comment: I would not recommend this to __anyone__ who "knows a bit of Python and starting to learn C". It's simply no beginner project.

Comment: This might be a little too large of a starter project ...

Comment: Maybe [linuxfromscratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) should help you.  but i highly doubt that this is related to C unless you're going to write your own package manager or something...

Comment: There's a difference in doing a remasterization and **writing** your own distro, I recommend looking for remastersys for debian/ubuntu and starting with that, also the Linux From Scratch project is a possible approach.

Comment: I doubt there's much programming involved in making your own distro (unless you are going to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/):

> Linux From Scratch (LFS) is a project that provides you with step-by-step instructions for building your own custom Linux system, entirely from source code.